# How to read a variable value in the AppDelegate from a ViewController using Swift

Tags: swift, var

I would like to read the value of a variable contained in the `AppDelegate` from a ViewController. The variable contains the `Device Token` used to enable iOS Push Notifications and I would like to show it in a `UILabel`.

This is my code so far:

**AppDelegate.swift**

```
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    internal var deviceTokenToPass: String?

    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        let pushNotificationsTypes: UIUserNotificationType = UIUserNotificationType.Alert | UIUserNotificationType.Badge | UIUserNotificationType.Sound
        let pushNotificationsSettings: UIUserNotificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: pushNotificationsTypes, categories: nil)

        application.registerUserNotificationSettings(pushNotificationsSettings)
        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

        return true
    }

    func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData) {
        let chararacterSet: NSCharacterSet = NSCharacterSet(charactersInString: "<>")
        self.deviceTokenToPass = (deviceToken.description as NSString).stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(chararacterSet).stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(" ", withString: "", options: nil, range: nil) as String
    }
}
```

**ViewController.swift**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var deviceTokenLabel : UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate
        var deviceToken = appDelegate.deviceTokenToPass

        println(deviceToken) /* nil */

        if deviceToken != nil {
            self.deviceTokenLabel.text = deviceToken
        } else {
            self.deviceTokenLabel.numberOfLines = 4
            self.deviceTokenLabel.text = "Cannot read your device token.\nYou must be using an iOS Simulator or you didn't allowed the application for push notifications"
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that if I place the `println(deviceToken)` code in the `AppDelegate.swift` the device token is correctly displayed in the console, if I place it in the `ViewController.swift` it's value will be **nil**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` notification is asynchronous (invoked after the device has been successfully registered), so what I think is happening is that the notification occurs *after* the view controller is displayed.

To check that, print it from both the app delegate and the view controller, and see which happens first.

As to how fix that, I would implement `didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError`, so that one of the 2 is invoked, then I would send a notification (via `NSNotificationCenter`) in both cases (success and failure), and store the outcome in a property.

In the view controller, I would subscribe for the custom notification, and show a progress view until a notification is received. But in `viewDidLoad` I'd also check for the outcome property set in the app delegate, just in case the registration is too fast and it's already been completed.

Answer (score 1):

If you ensure that the property that you'd like to access is actually readable, then you can use the following:

```
 let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate
 let anAttribute = appDelegate.theAttribute
```

Comment: Hello, I you look to my code I currently use the same code you posted but this doesn't work :-/

Comment: use as! as from Swift 2.0 ->  
var myDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

Answer (score 0):

in app delegate

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    weak var label: UILabel? = nil

    func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData) {
        let chararacterSet: NSCharacterSet = NSCharacterSet(charactersInString: "<>")
        let deviceTokenToPass = (deviceToken.description as NSString).stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(chararacterSet).stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(" ", withString: "", options: nil, range: nil) as String
        if let l = label {
            l.text = deviceTokenToPass
        }
    }

    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        let pushNotificationsTypes: UIUserNotificationType = UIUserNotificationType.Alert | UIUserNotificationType.Badge | UIUserNotificationType.Sound
        let pushNotificationsSettings: UIUserNotificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: pushNotificationsTypes, categories: nil)

        application.registerUserNotificationSettings(pushNotificationsSettings)
        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

        return true
    }
}
```

in ViewController

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var deviceTokenLabel : UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as? AppDelegate {
            appDelegate.label = deviceTokenLabel
        }

    }
}
```